# bitcoin core. 0/no confirmations, in the memory pool

Tags: transactions

I ask for help, today I sent bits from my core wallet, everything was as usual.an hour after sending, I checked the transaction in the blockchain and it's not there at all, as if I didn't send it....the transaction did not appear online! .who can tell me what's the matter?? txid 18ba35a6bbf99796d16cd9319b8035e38b4b5ce1a6fe7fe1c66084f9f6f96708

Comment: Did you send your transaction with a feerate of less than 10 sat/vB?